# Simple Search for Files in C

Tags: c, string, file, search

I am learning to program in C and I'm working on a little project: a Library Management Software. The problem I'm having is to make the search function work. I know my code is really simple and inefficient if I work with a lot of data, but since that's not the case, I think it should work.
Here is the function i wrote:

```
void search_for_book (FILE *BooksFile) {
    BooksFile = fopen("Data.txt", "a+");

    char book_title[100], test_book[100], author[100], category[100];
    int answer, status, more_books;

    more_books: // To search for more books

    printf("Type the title of the book you would like to look for:\n");
    scanf("%s", book_title);

    while(!feof(BooksFile)){
        fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", test_book);

        if(strcmp(book_title, test_book) == 0) { // strcmp returns zero if strings are equal
            printf("The book you informed was found.\n");
            printf("Do you want to see its information? Type 1 for yes and 2 for no.\n");
            scanf("%d", &answer);

            if (answer == 1) { // User wants information
                fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", author);
                fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", category);
                fscanf(BooksFile, "%d", &status);

                printf("Book's title: %s\n", book_title);
                printf("Book's author: %s\n", author);
                printf("Book's category: %s\n", category);
                printf("Book's status: %d\n", status);

                break;

            } else { // User doesn't want information
                printf("Would you like to search for another book? Type zero if that's the case.\n");
                scanf("%d", &more_books);

                if (more_books == 0) {
                    goto more_books;
                }

                break;
            }
        }
    } 
}
```

What's wrong with my code and how can I fix it? When I call for this function, the program only executes the printf (asking to type the book's title), and then simply goes back to the main function, not seaching for anything.

Comment: Avoid `goto` in c first. it's to dangerous to jump between inside/outside loop using `goto`? how it works?

Comment: You might try telling (*in the question please*) what appears **not** to be working, or working *differently* than you expect.

Comment: Send it to the code review part.

Comment: What were you took error? More explain pls? (ex: I have pointer error on blabla line)

Comment: I don't really get an error. When I call for that function, the program executes the printf (asking to type the book's title) and doesn't seach for the book

Comment: @user3368101 can show `Data.txt`?

Comment: Sure. On my program there is also an add_book function that is working well. The Data.txt file: "Murder_on_the_Orient_Express"
Agatha_Christie
Mystery
1

"1984"
George_Orwell
Dystopia
1

"The_Maze_Runner"
James_Dashner
Thriller
2

"Thinking_Fast_and_Slow"
Daniel_Kahneman
Decision_Making
3

Comment: My opinion, your Data.txt file and your debug file must be same directory. Did you control files directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code seems inefficient and i don't know why you passed file pointer in `search_for_book` function instead you can take locally and open with it. i have made some modification in your function try with it.

```
void search_for_book() 
{
    FILE *BooksFile;

    BooksFile = fopen("Data.txt", "r");

    char book_title[100], test_book[100], author[100], category[100];
    int answer, status, more_books;

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Type the title of the book you would like to look for:\n");
        scanf("%s", book_title);

        while(!feof(BooksFile))
        {
            fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", test_book);

            if(strcmp(book_title, test_book) == 0) 
            { 
                printf("The book you informed was found.\n");
                printf("Do you want to see its information? Type 1 for yes and 2 for no.\n");
                scanf("%d", &answer);

                if (answer == 1) 
                { 
                    // User wants information
                    fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", author);
                    fscanf(BooksFile, "%s", category);
                    fscanf(BooksFile, "%d", &status);

                    printf("Book's title: %s\n", book_title);
                    printf("Book's author: %s\n", author);
                    printf("Book's category: %s\n", category);
                    printf("Book's status: %d\n", status);
                    break;
                } 

            }
        } 

        rewind(BooksFile);
        printf("Would you like to search for another book? Type zero if that's the case.\n");
        scanf("%d",&more_books);

        if(more_books == 1)
         continue;
        else
          break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- Open the file with "r" rather than "a+", a+ is for append and the end of the file, you are not writing to it.

  It looks like you file contains title, author, category and then status, when you search you read all lines, so you might find the text you look for in the author line. Read all the data for each book even if you don't need it.

  When you go back to more_books, you don't rewind the file. Try fseek(0, SEEK_SET). Or close / re-open the file.

  Type to replace the goto by a for loop, it's easier to read (though goto is unpopular but works).

Comment: Modified my code, but the searching isn't working yet. Thank you for the suggestions!

Comment: You can try to replace fscanf("%s") with gets, that's simpler. Also beware you have to type the exact Uppercase and lowercase of the title, use stricmp to avoid that. Also beware there might be a nasty '\n' character somewhere in your strings ;)